# Why is my line clipping in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a series of lines.  The lines are all the same length, and randomly switch colors for a random length (blue to orange).  I am drawing the lines in blue and then overlaying orange on top.  You can see from my picture there are clipped parts of the lines where it is grey.  I cannot figure out why this is happening.  Also related I believe is that my labels are not moving to a left alignment like they should.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Clipping bar graph]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import random

plt.close('all')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,11))


def label(xy, text):
    y = xy[1] - 2
    ax.text(xy[0], y, text, ha="left", family='sans-serif', size=14)


def draw_chromosome(start, stop, y, color):
    x = np.array([start, stop])
    y = np.array([y, y])
    line = mlines.Line2D(x , y, lw=10., color=color)
    ax.add_line(line)


x = 50
y = 100
chr = 1

for i in range(22):
    draw_chromosome(x, 120, y, "#1C2F4D")

    j = 0
    while j < 120:
        print j
        length = 1
        if random.randint(1, 100) > 90:
            length = random.randint(1, 120-j)
            draw_chromosome(j, j+length, y, "#FA9B00")
        j = j+length+1
    label([x, y], "Chromosome%i" % chr)

    y -= 3
    chr += 1


plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have a look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html which will greatly simplify this code.  You might also have a look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_barh.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only drawing the blue background from x = 50 to x = 120.

Replace this line:

```
draw_chromosome(x, 120, y, "#1C2F4D")
```

with this:

```
draw_chromosome(0, 120, y, "#1C2F4D")
```

To draw the blue line all the way across.

Alternately, if you also want to move your labels to the left, you can just set `x=0` instead of setting it to 50.

Comment: I see, how foolish of me, I had j initialized to 0 instead of 50.  I was wanting to start at 50 to indent a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `LineCollection` for this.  Below is a little helper function I wrote based on the example at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html (it looks long, but there is a lot of comments + docstrings)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import NullLocator
from collections import OrderedDict


def binary_state_lines(ax, chrom_data, xmin=0, xmax=120,
                       delta_y=3, 
                       off_color = "#1C2F4D",
                       on_color = "#FA9B00"):
    """
    Draw a whole bunch of chromosomes

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : Axes
        The axes to draw stuff to

    chrom_data : OrderedDict
        The chromosome data as a dict, key on the label with a list of pairs
        of where the data is 'on'.  Data is plotted top-down

    xmin, xmax : float, optional
        The minimum and maximum limits for the x values

    delta_y : float, optional
        The spacing between lines

    off_color, on_color : color, optional
        The colors to use for the the on/off state

    Returns
    -------
    collections : dict
        dictionary of the collections added keyed on the label

    """
    # base offset
    y_val = 0
    # make the color map and norm
    cmap = ListedColormap([off_color, on_color])
    norm = BoundaryNorm([0, 0.5, 1], cmap.N)
    # sort out where the text should be
    txt_x = (xmax + xmin) / 2
    # dictionary to hold the returned artists
    ret = dict()
    # loop over the input data draw each collection
    for label, data in chrom_data.items():
        # increment the y offset
        y_val += delta_y
        # turn the high windows on to alternating
        # high/low regions
        x = np.asarray(data).ravel()
        # assign the high/low state to each one
        state = np.mod(1 + np.arange(len(x)), 2)
        # deal with boundary conditions to be off
        # at start/end
        if x[0] > xmin:
            x = np.r_[xmin, x]
            state = np.r_[0, state]
        if x[-1] < xmax:
            x = np.r_[x, xmax]
            state = np.r_[state, 0]
        # make the matching y values
        y = np.ones(len(x)) * y_val
        # call helper function to create the collection
        coll = draw_segments(ax, x, y, state,
                                     cmap, norm)
        ret[label] = coll

    # set up the axes limits
    ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(0, y_val + delta_y)
    # turn off x-ticks
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator())
    # make the y-ticks be labeled as per the input
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks((1 + np.arange(len(chrom_data))) * delta_y)
    ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(list(chrom_data.keys()))
    # invert so that the first data is at the top
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    # turn off the frame and patch
    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    # return the added artists
    return ret

def draw_segments(ax, x, y, state, cmap, norm, lw=10):
    """
    helper function to turn boundary edges into the input LineCollection
    expects.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : Axes
       The axes to draw to

    x, y, state : array
       The x edges, the y values and the state of each region

    cmap : matplotlib.colors.Colormap
       The color map to use

    norm : matplotlib.ticker.Norm
       The norm to use with the color map

    lw : float, optional
       The width of the lines
    """

    points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
    lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    lc.set_array(state)
    lc.set_linewidth(lw)

    ax.add_collection(lc)
    return lc
```

An example:

```
synthetic_data = OrderedDict()
for j in range(21):
    key = 'data {:02d}'.format(j)
    synthetic_data[key] = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(1, 10, 20)).reshape(-1, 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
binary_state_lines(ax, synthetic_data, xmax=120)
plt.show()
```

[image: example output]

Separating the plotting logic from everything else will make your code easier to maintain and more reusable.

I also took the liberty of moving your labels from between the lines (where they can be ambiguous) to the yaxis tick labels.